# set childNodes dynamicly styles with array of colors in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, arrays, foreach

I want to give each `div` or `childNodes` a different color using an array of colors
But only the last color of the array is given to all the divs or childNodes.

Can you tell me how we can dynamically style them by `mapping` or `forEach` nodes,childNodes,dives and colors in `reactjs`?

you can see demo:  [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-water-2br0d3?file=/src/App.js)

```
const containerRef = useRef()

    useEffect(()=>{
        containerRef.current.childNodes.forEach(item=>{
          ['green','blue','green','yellow','orange'].map(colors => {
            item.style.background = colors 
         })
        })
      })


    <div 
          ref={containerRef }
          className="h-96 w-full flex items-center gap-x-6 border border-black">
            <div className='w-20 h-20 border border-black'>one</div>
            <div className='w-20 h-20 border border-black'>two</div>
            <div className='w-20 h-20 border border-black'>three</div>
            <div className='w-20 h-20 border border-black'>four</div>
            <div className='w-20 h-20 border border-black'>five</div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `map` the colors, you just need to assign each element with a corresponding index of color.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const containerRef = useRef();
  const colors = ["green", "blue", "green", "yellow", "orange"];

  useEffect(() => {
    containerRef.current.childNodes.forEach((item, i) => {
      item.style.background = colors[i];
    });
  });
  return (
    <div ref={containerRef} className="container">
      <div>one</div>
      <div>two</div>
      <div>three</div>
      <div>four</div>
      <div>five</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-river-gkmyyp?file=/src/App.js:0-528)

Answer (score 0):

Here you're mapping again on `colors`, for each `item` in child nodes which results in assigning the last color to each `div`.

You will have to use the `index` of the item in the childNodes list, and access the color of that `index` from the `colors` array.

CodeSanbox Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-frost-3v0v76